# How can I join 45 degree mitered boards as legs for a coffee table?

Tags: joinery

I'm looking to duplicate this look for a wooden coffee table:
https://www.scandesign.com/products/porto-coffee-table

Any ideas on how I could replicate those coffee table legs other than mortise and tenon? I don't believe I have the skills for that. 
Tools I have: 10" sliding miter saw, kreg pocket hole jig.

[image: coffee table image]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  Could you add to your question what tools (especially power tools such as a tablesaw) you have for building this project.

Comment: FWIW: Mortise and tenon joints aren't as hard as they look if you take your time doing it. You may not think you have the skills now, but by the time you've done it a few times, you will. Give it a shot on some "extra" wood and see how it goes. You may find it easier to deal with than pocket screws. I'm not sure either is the best choice for this particular application tho. I'd suggest dowels or splines maybe.

Comment: Before considering the joinery you should realize that will be a fairly tricky joint to pull off.  You will need very accurate 45 degree angles and all matching pieces must be exactly the same length in order to not have any gaps in the joints.  I wouldn't attempt this with a circular saw.  If using a miter saw definitely do some test cuts to make sure that it is cutting accurately before cutting your work piece.  If possible gang your pieces together or use a stop to make sure they all end up the same length.

Comment: I know you've asked about the leg joints specifically but those could be considered the simplest aspect of this, since as a coffee table this would not typically take much weight and the wood is beefy meaning there's plenty of glue surface area. So even without reinforcement simple mitres *might* be sufficient. However, this table design has 2 other features that should potentially be of greater concern, the first being the top boards and how they're joined (if they are joined), the second how that top attaches to the leg frames (especially if the boards are intended to remain separate)..

Comment: @Graphus thank you for the comments. I'm not looking to replicate the table exactly. I want to make it square and large enough to drop, in the middle, a metal bowl for a gas firepit. I'd like the top to be similar but it will probably have a few extra boards under it for support. Something like this: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/35/d8/8035d8ca74a62e49188cc7928503d964.jpg

Comment: That additional pic gives a better idea of what you're going for, thanks. Since this is an exterior project forget what I said previously about the mitres! Just to keep this brief I recommend you reinforce with screws. Pocket screws would work (picking the locations carefully to minimise visibility) but you must use exterior-rated screws in case that's not obvious. You should glue as well for max strength and you can go with a waterproof PVA, polyurethane or epoxy. Shouldn't really matter which so if you need to buy for this project pick what's cheapest, they're all waterproof enough for this.